# Htaccess Mismatch if Parameter String too Similar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create my own blog, but struggle with a problem where too similar URLs cause a mismatch. Let's say I have an article "`blog/how_to_become_developer`" and then "`blog/how_to_become_designer`". I type in the second, but I see the first article instead of the second. I faced it elsewhere when the parameter starts similarity.

A better example:
I have the URL `myurl.com/blog/how_to_become_developer`. This is the rewritten URL for `myurl.com/app.php?url=blog&blog=how_to_become_developer`.

With the second parameter, blog, I look up the article in a json-file. I thought JSON would be the problem but the problem also appears if I have a similar setting for `myurl.com/invitationhub/` and `myurl.com/invite`, so I changed the latter one to `myurl.com/ivite` just to work on it.

The line I use in my htaccess-file is

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ /app.php?url=blog&blog=$1 [NC,L]
```

But where's the catch? 'cause based on my search it doesn't seem to be a problem that many people have.

Comment: Could you please do mention from which url to which url(in back-end; you want to serve), for better understanding of your question here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, done. Updated the original post.

Comment: Your regex pattern matches anything followed by `blog/` . It matches `/blog/how_to_become_developer` and also matches `/blog/how_to_become_designer` . There is nothing you can do to prevent this except changing your URL format.

Comment: @AmitVerma So normally it should work as I want? Regarding changing, can you provide an example?

Comment: You can change it  something like `/blog/dev/how_to_become_a_developer` and change the pattern to `^blog/dev/([^/]*)$` so that your rule  triggers only when the request is for this URL.

Comment: I don’t see how the shown RewriteRule should cause that kind of problem here. This much rather sounds like your selection of data from the JSON file afterwards might be faulty. Have you made a debug output of the `blog` parameter to verify what that contains in each case?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples only. Though I am not sure if you are exactly looking for this one, I am catching last part of string which comes after `how_to_become` here and passing it to `blog=$1` part in rewriting url.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/how_to_become_([^/]*)/?$ /app.php?url=blog&blog=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also change `/app.php` to `app.php` in above in case file app.php is not present in root directory.